# Select simple value in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I want to show a text summary for a model in a Rails application.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
class ServiceOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, class_name: 'ServiceOrderItem', 
                   dependent: :destroy,
                   inverse_of: :service_order

  def link_text
    items.left_outer_joins(:product)
      .select("string_agg(coalesce(products.description, service_order_items.description), '; ') as description")
      .group("service_order_items.service_order_id")
      .map(&:description)
      .first
  end
end

class ServiceOrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service_order, inverse_of: :items
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
end
```

What bothers me is that I'm trying to select a single value, and not a model.

This query does return a "fake" model and extract the value I want, but it's kind of hacky:

1. Add proper relations I need

   - `items.left_outer_joins(:product)`
2. Add the select value I want

   - `.select("string_agg(coalesce(products.description, service_order_items.description), '; ') as description")`
3. Add group by clause

   - `.group("service_order_items.service_order_id")`
4. Execute the query and extract the description of the "fake" model returned

   - `.map(&:description)`
5. I know this query only returns a single result, but it builds an array with all results, so I extract the single result out of the array

   - `.first`

The query I want is this:

```
select string_agg(coalesce(products.description, service_order_items.description), '; ')
  from service_order_items
  left outer join products on service_order_items.product_id = products.id
  where service_order_items.service_order_id = :id
  group by service_order_items.service_order_id;
```

And this is the query I'm generating, the problem is that the result is enclosed in a model object, then I transform it into an array and then I extract the value I want.

So, how do I tell active record to select a single raw value and not a list of models?

By the way, adding `.first` before `.map` doesn't work because it includes an order by in the executed SQL that I can't have (`order by service_order_items.id`).

The schema:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "organization_id"
  t.string   "code"
  t.string   "description"
  t.string   "brand"
  t.string   "unit_of_measure"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.decimal  "selling_price"
  t.index ["organization_id"], name: "index_products_on_organization_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "service_order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "service_order_id"
  t.decimal  "quantity"
  t.string   "description"
  t.integer  "product_id"
  t.decimal  "unit_price"
  t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_service_order_items_on_product_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["service_order_id"], name: "index_service_order_items_on_service_order_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "service_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "organization_id"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "state_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.integer  "customer_id"
  t.integer  "sequential_id"
  t.date     "start_date"
  t.date     "end_date"
  t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_service_orders_on_customer_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["organization_id"], name: "index_service_orders_on_organization_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["state_id"], name: "index_service_orders_on_state_id", using: :btree
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New answer

The need to use the description on `service_order_items` if there isn't a product makes this a little tricky. If you want to keep your custom SQL, it should be possible to use [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) with the same text as your `select` (minus the `as description` part):

```
def link_text
  items.left_outer_joins(:product)
    .group("service_order_items.service_order_id")
    .pluck("string_agg(coalesce(products.description, service_order_items.description), '; ')")
    .first
end
```

You also mentioned that you couldn't use `first` before `map` because it introduced an undesired order; you could try using [`take`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take) instead of `first` to avoid that, in which case you wouldn't need `pluck`.

Note that in either case you're introducing some dependencies on the table names, which could cause problems in more complex queries that require table aliases. If you want to go for less custom SQL,
the most direct way I can think of is to add the following method (probably with a name that better fits your application) to `ServiceOrderItem`:

```
def description_for_link_text
  product.try(:description) || description
end
```

Then in `ServiceOrder`:

```
def link_text
  items.includes(:product).map(&:description_for_link_text).join('; ')
end
```

The `includes(:product)` should avoid the [N+1 issue](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) where you do one query to get the items and then another query for each product. If you have a page that's displaying this text for multiple service orders, you have to deal with another level of this; often you have to declare a whole bunch of tables in `includes` even if they're declared in the `link_text` method.

```
service_orders = ServiceOrder.some_query_or_scope.includes(items: :product)
service_orders.each { |so| puts so.link_text }
```

If you do this, I don't think you actually have to have the `includes` in `link_text` itself, but if you removed it from there and you called `link_text` in any other situation, you'd get the N+1 issue again.

## Original answer

I'm a bit confused by how your schema fits together: do `service_orders` and `items` have a one-to-many relationship, or a many-to-many relationship? How does `products` relate to `items`? And I don't have quite enough reputation to comment to ask.

In general, you can use [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to get an array of values with just the attributes you want. I don't know off the top of my head if it works on virtual attributes, but you may be able to define [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationships so that you don't need to define `string_agg(products.description, '; ') as description` to join the strings together. That is, if your `ServiceOrder` model is able to have a `products` association like:

```
has_many :items
has_many :products, through: :items
```

then you could then just define `link_text` as `products.pluck(:description).join("; ")`. You may need to play around with your `has_many :through` definition in order to get it to work right with your schema. Also, doing it this way does mean you have to watch out for potential N+1 query issues; see the [Rails guide section on eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for how to address that.

Comment: Hey Max, your suggestion did work, but it misses the case when the item doesn't have an associated product. I've edited the question to clarify the schema and also updated the SQL to account for items without products (it's a left outer join with `coalesce`).

Comment: @ThiagoNegri Thanks, I tried to address the `coalesce` issue with new edits. Does that work better?

Comment: It worked like a charm! Do you know whether it's possible to do a "conditional includes"? For example, I only need to include the products of items without descriptions. I ask this because the "service order" itself contains a "description" field, so the "link_text" is only used when the service order has no description, so for that particular service order it's unnecessary to include items and products.

Comment: @ThiagoNegri I don't think so, but it shouldn't matter that much. All the `includes` does is fetch the service orders, items, and products ahead of time with only a few queries and load that into memory so that when you do call `link_text` it doesn't have to query the database for each item (which could cause issues with performance). I'm not a database tuning expert, but I don't think asking for more items than you need will have a significant impact on performance unless the proportions are pretty drastic. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: (...continued from previous comment) If you needed to, you could try splitting your initial service order load into `ServiceOrder.some_query.where(description: nil)` and `ServiceOrder.some_query.where.not(description: nil).includes(items: :product)`. But I'm not sure that would be more efficient than just calling `includes` for the whole thing.